# When should I use the negative milestone unlocks?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

The most recent timed event zone of Adventure Capitalist, "New You", has a set of paired investments, a healthy and slow option and a corresponding unhealthy and fast. Every other milestone unlock for the unhealthy option sabotages the speed of the already slow healthy option.

Currently I'm just buying 25 of the unhealthy investments to get to the first unlock (which boosts the unhealthy investment without sabotaging the healthy) and open up some of the "X of everything" unlocks, then focusing entirely on the healthy investments. I'm not sure if this is the optimal strategy to unlock everything before the timed event expires, but I am nervous about too much sabotage to the healthy investments.

[image: new you event]

**When should I purchase the unhealthy investments so that I can unlock all of the badges, megabucks and gold milestones without crippling the income from my healthy investments?**

Comment: You can invest in the right side just before 1 more level to have to speeds reduction for the left side. For example, you could upgrade Com-Fy boys (the chair) till level 49, to get most profit without the penalty on the shred-mills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen any "most efficient" guides, but this is what I did and completed it already.

I started with getting the first unlock in each option, which i will refer to as the **left** (healthy) and **right** (unhealthy) sides.  Every second unlock on the right is negative (80% profit speed of left side), so I would suggest avoiding the negative unlocks as long as possible.  At first you may need to unlock the first 3 unlocks on the right to get extra profit (2 positive unlocks for right, 1 negative for left), but I would focus on the left side.

After getting enough angels, roughly after 1-3 resets, to reset fairly quickly, then I would get 30 in each on the right (to avoid the second unlock).  After that I would only focus on the left, until at some point you will max out the left side (75 up to ~275 in each).

Once you can max out the left side, then focus on the right until you unlock everything.  Once you unlock the left side, it is pretty easy to max out the rest.  Don't forget to max out the carrots at 100 for the unlock everything x100 unlock, since it maxes out around 75.

Comment: Just curious, do you reset like you would the other planets (i.e. 100-200 first time, then reset whenever you would double up?).  Also, I was wondering if it made any sense to focus on mystery meat on the right side since it only effect veggies which doesn't seem to get a profit upgrade like the others, only speed upgrade for everything.

Comment: For angels, I would go with what your normal amount is, but that sounds like a good starting range.  After that it should be a lot easier to double up angels afterwards.  For Mystery Meat, i thought about doing that, but I never had to.  To start off it would probably help more, but once you are resetting often, the right side is almost useless until the left side is maxed out.  The difference is that carrots would start making a bigger difference once you get up around 20-30 carrots (maybe a bit more) because it gives x2 profit speed on each unlock.